# Loop em um arquivo sendo lido em C

Tags: c, arquivo, loop

Bom, estou tentando ler de um arquivo, e criar um loop para que eu possa passar por todos os caracteres até encontrar caractere '<'. Após encontrar esse caractere, o programa deve ler e guardar as informações lidar até encontrar um '\n', para serem posteriormente processadas, e até aí acontece tudo bem.

O problema acontece se antes dessas ações ocorrerem eu inserir um  `while((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF)` com a intenção de começar a ler o texto novamente até encontrar o próximo caractere '<' para realizar a operação novamente, e parar somente no fim do arquivo.

Com o while incluído, eu recebo um segmentation fault. Já tentei criar uma variável temporária para armazenar a posição da variável `ch`, porém o segmentation fault continua ocorrendo.

Como posso resolver este problema?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  char s[100];
  char ch;
  FILE *in_file  = fopen("name_of_file", "r"); 
  
  while((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF){  //aqui acontece o erro. sem essa tentativa de loop, os 2 for's que se seguem ocorrem sem erros

      for(ch = fgetc(in_file);ch != '<';ch = fgetc(in_file)){
          }
      i=0;
      for(ch = fgetc(in_file);ch != '\n';ch = fgetc(in_file)){
        s[i] = ch;
        i++;
      }
      s[i] = '\0';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: EOF retorna quando você chegou ao final do arquivo, ou algum erro aconteceu. 

O que acontece se enquanto você estiver no 1º ou 2º for não encontrar nenhum '<' ou '\n' ele ficará lendo infinitamente.   

Você precisa verificar se chegou ao final do arquivo enquanto está lendo isso.
O while só irá testar isto, quando os dois fors terminarem a sua execução pelos seus próprios testes.

Comment: Você devia usar apenas um loop, testando nesse se chega ao `<` ou ao `\n` ou ao fim do arquivo. Essa alteração de lógica resolve o problema que tem na totalidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está a fazer várias leituras e em apenas uma delas, no `while`, é que verifica se atingiu o fim do arquivo. Consegue resolver o problema trocando os vários *loops* por um só. Assumindo que precisa de construir strings com tudo o que vem entre `<` e `\n` então pode alterar a lógica do seu programa para a seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0, save_str = 0, pos = 0; //mais duas variáveis de controle
  char s[100];
  char ch;
  FILE *in_file  = fopen("name_of_file", "r");

  while((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF){
    if (ch == '\n'){ //chegou ao \n fecha a string construida
        s[pos] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador que já tinha
        //utilizar a string
        save_str = 0;
    }
    if (save_str){
        s[pos++] = ch;
    }
    if (ch == '<'){ //achou < começa a construir a string daqui para a frente
        save_str = 1;
        pos = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note que:

- O teste de `\n` é feito antes de acrescentar o caratere à string de forma a que o `\n` não seja incluído na string
- O `save_str` é na verdade um booleano ao estilo do C para indicar quando está ou não a construir a string.